# C# Class Library method summaries are not showing in intellisense

Tags: c#, documentation, intellisense

Fairly self-explanatory I feel

Comment: It's not self-explanatory.  First of all, is this your class library or something off-the-shelf?

Comment: Is Intellisense working for anything?

Comment: @Aaronnaught - right you are, it is my own class library. Problem solved now though

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but if this is your class library, you have to make sure you actually build the XML documentation file, otherwise the method summaries will only be available from within the same assembly.

Project Properties -> Build Tab -> Output section -> Check "XML documentation file"

Obviously, as Mitchel points out, you have to import it too, but this is generally automatic when you add an assembly reference (as long as it exists).

Comment: Accepted this over Mitchel's answer (as right as it is) because I hadn't performed the previous step outlined in this answer to generate the xml file in the first place

Comment: This also explains why 

"Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member"

is not there to remind you to document. [as default for Libraries]

Comment: Just had another isssue: Do not rename the Xml file in the project's properties. I am guessing that intellisense looks for an xml that has the same name as the dll or the namespace or the solution. It won't get picked up if you give it any custom name. I wonder how you can build .dlls as a single file without having to create that xml...

Answer (score 7):

When you build the class library, be sure to put the .xml file that has the documentation in the same folder as the .dll.  Intellisense will then pick this up.