# How do I turn on IntelliSense documentation in Visual Studio for system libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm running Visual Studio Community 2017 and none of the system library documentation summaries show in IntelliSense. I can't find an option to turn it on. Did I just miss in installing it or is there some way to turn this feature on?

Comment: Hi redcurry, how did you check the intellisense for the system library? I tested it on my side and invoke the system method, right click the method name and choose ‘Peek Definition’, then move the mouse on the method name and it popups the quick info message, it seems the summary display correctly:https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgx3mb4Xa8P7YL-cy, if I misunderstand, please provide the screenshot or more detail information. If it is the custom Class Library, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387959/c-sharp-class-library-method-summaries-are-not-showing-in-intellisense?rq=1

Comment: Hi Sara, I tested it exactly as you said. However, I created a new test project and the IntelliSense worked. Now in my actual project it's working as well. It's as if the test project somehow turned on this feature. Thanks for your help.